Issue with Disappearing Tab Content in Dynamics 365 (RTL langauge)
Good afternoon,
Have you encountered a situation where tab content on a form occasionally disappears after scrolling down? This issue occurs intermittently and affects different tabs. When refreshing the page, the content appears correctly.
Instead of grids, messages are displayed on the side of the screen, indicating the number of records in each grid.
We are currently using version 9.1.28.09 of Dynamics on-premise on RTL language.
Thank you.
--------Update----------
It seems that this occurs only when there is an editable grid at the bottom of the form that requires scrolling to reach
